# How Can We Directly Take an Integer and Use It as a Number of Days?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

`Rails 5.1.4`

In
`app/controllers/application_controller.rb`
how the heck is this valid:
`2.days.seconds.to_i` ?

Doing: `puts 2.days.seconds.to_i`
Yields: `` undefined method `days' for 2:Integer (NoMethodError) ``

So, how does it work there in Rails?

Comment: Are you asking why it works in rails and not straight ruby?

Comment: Well, I haven't used Rails in a while but you obviously have a calendar gem that adds a converter to the Integer class. (Yes that answer is not of much help, Sorry ^^) EDIT: If the question was actually HOW did they do it, you can add methods to existing classes (or overwirte some) by redifining it (`class Integer; def days; '''TADADADA'''; end; end`)

Comment: Similarly in ```config/environments/test.rb``` I C: ```1.hour.seconds.to_i```
There are probably other instances elsewhere, but these are first 2 I noticed.

Comment: You do know, we can't see your code right?

Comment: add `require 'active_support/all` and try. This is were it is coming form.!

Answer (score 2):

Rails adds many extensions to Ruby classes.

`days` is a method that Rails adds to numeric

> Returns a Duration instance matching the number of days provided.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Numeric.html#method-i-days

Comment: Yes...when _Cyril Lemaire_ mentioned above...that got me thinking about that. Yes, started learning Rails with a couple of books, and am just trying to understand little bit of the 'magic' - see what's 'behind the curtain,' so to speak.